# Setting css style to the body of one particular page, which shares a common header.ejs file

Tags: html, css, node.js, css-selectors, ejs

I have a common header.ejs and footer.ejs in my partials directory which is shared among all other pages in the views directory, which means that all files share a common body tag or element. I want to set a different background color to the body of one particular page in the views directory. Is there anyway to do that?

Answer (score 0):

In your page, since your header has the stylesheets, if you link more *underneath* them, the previous styles are **overidden** by the new one. Meaning if you had a styles.css in your header.ejs that stated that the body should be blue, and in your file (eg login.ejs) you linked a stylesheet **undernearth** the `<%- include('partials/header') %>` that that states that the body should be light green, the second stylesheet, i.e the one under the include tag, will override that body style.